# Add fragment into viewPager's fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have viewpager with 3 fragments (same layout - some EditText and Buttons) and I want to dynamically add small fragment above the viewpager fragment, write something in and then hide it.

This is what I tried:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {
                case 0: return MainFragment.newInstance("1");
                case 1: return MainFragment.newInstance("2");
                case 2: return MainFragment.newInstance("3");
                default: return MainFragment.newInstance("");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }
}
```

MainFragment.java:

```
public class MainFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    EditText contentEdit;
    String content, ID;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ID = getArguments().getString("msg");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        contentEdit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);

        contentEdit.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getActivity()) {
              public void onSwipeBottom() {
                  final ViewGroup newView = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_title, container, false);

                  newView.findViewById(R.id.delete_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(View view) {
                          container.removeView(newView);
                      }
                  });
                  container.addView(newView, 0);
              }

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put a frame layout above that viewPager layout BUT set it's visibility to GONE therefore it won't "exist". Now in your pager onItemClick listener for that small fragment you want to show call findViewByID(R.id.YourFrameLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); and when you want to hide it, well you get the idea. Don't forget to add your fragment to that container, e.g. YourFrameLayout

Comment: Glad to help (Nemáš za čo) :)